# Problem with per-triangle collision detection when geometry is rotated

Tags: c#, collision-detection, matrix-multiplication, sharpdx

For my game, I am attempting to implement per-triangle collision detection with the camera. It appears as though the code is mostly working, in that non-rotated geometry is correctly hit-tested, and stops the camera. However, the problem arises when I attempt to move the camera into any piece of rotated geometry. I'm going to provide a few pictures to help illustrate my problem, as well as the code that I'm currently using for collision detection. It should be noted that I'm using SharpDX as a 3D library.

In this picture, I am correctly hit-testing the wall beside me. I cannot penetrate it from any direction. This piece of geometry is not rotated.
[image]

In this picture I am correctly hit-testing the floor below me. Again, it is not rotated.
[image]

In this picture, I circle a series of pieces of geometry, all of which are rotated by 270 degrees on the Y axis. I can pass right through these pieces.
[image]

In this picture I am hitting something head-on, which is causing my hit-detection to trigger. You will see in the next picture what this "something" is.
[image]

Finally, here is a picture of those pieces of rotated geometry without rotation. I correctly hit-detect them in this state. When they're rotated, the hitboxes remain in the same location as you visually see them in this picture, which is why I hit "something" in front of them.
[image]

Here is my current code for camera hit detection (Updated for better readability):

```
if (isCameraMoving)
            {
                foreach (StaticGeometry geometry in this.StaticGeometry)
                {
                    BoundingSphere cameraSphere = Camera.Bounds;
                    for (int i = 0; i < geometry.Mesh.Vertices.Length; i += 3)
                    {
                        // Get the Vertex Positions for the current Triangle
                        Vector3 position1 = geometry.Mesh.Vertices[i].Location;
                        Vector3 position2 = geometry.Mesh.Vertices[i + 1].Location;
                        Vector3 position3 = geometry.Mesh.Vertices[i + 2].Location;

                        // Create the rotation matrix using the geometry's current rotation setting.
                        Matrix rotationMatrix = VoidwalkerMath.CreateRotationMatrix(geometry.Rotation);

                        // rotate and translate each vertex
                        Matrix matrix1 = rotationMatrix * Matrix.Translation(position1 + geometry.Location);
                        Matrix matrix2 = rotationMatrix * Matrix.Translation(position2 + geometry.Location);
                        Matrix matrix3 = rotationMatrix * Matrix.Translation(position3 + geometry.Location);

                        // extract the new position from the rotated and translated Matrices.
                        Vector3 finalVertexLocation1 = matrix1.TranslationVector;
                        Vector3 finalVertexLocation2 = matrix2.TranslationVector;
                        Vector3 finalVertexLocation3 = matrix3.TranslationVector;

                        // Do hit detection for a triangle.
                        if (cameraSphere.Intersects(ref finalVertexLocation1, ref finalVertexLocation2, ref finalVertexLocation3))
                        {
                            this.Camera.Location = previousCameraPosition;
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

And my code for creating a rotation matrix. I'm positive this code works as intended, because it's the same function I use for rotating my geometry.

```
/// <summary>
        /// Converts degrees to radians.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="degrees">The angle in degrees.</param>
        public static float ToRadians(float degrees)
        {
            return degrees / 360.0f * TwoPi;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a rotation matrix using degrees.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="xDegrees"></param>
        /// <param name="yDegrees"></param>
        /// <param name="zDegrees"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Matrix CreateRotationMatrix(float xDegrees, float yDegrees, float zDegrees)
        {
            return
                Matrix.RotationX(ToRadians(xDegrees)) *
                Matrix.RotationY(ToRadians(yDegrees)) *
                Matrix.RotationZ(ToRadians(zDegrees));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts a Vector3 of Degrees to a Vector3 of Radians
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="degrees"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Vector3 ToRadians(Vector3 degrees)
        {
            return ToRadians(degrees.X,degrees.Y,degrees.Z);
        }
```

And here is my Vertex class. If you guys need anything else, just let me know.

```
using SharpDX;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace VoidwalkerEngine.Framework.DirectX.Rendering
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Vertex
    {

        public static Vertex Zero = new Vertex(Vector3.Zero,Vector2.Zero,Vector3.Zero);

        public Vector3 Location;
        public Vector2 TexCoords;
        public Vector3 Normal;

        public const int Size = 32;


        public Vertex(Vector3 position, Vector2 texCoords, Vector3 normal)
        {
            this.Location = position;
            this.Normal = normal;
            this.TexCoords = texCoords;
        }

        public Vertex(Vertex other)
        {
            this.Location = other.Location;
            this.Normal = other.Normal;
            this.TexCoords = other.TexCoords;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return
                "Location: " + Location.ToString() +
                ", TexCoords: " + TexCoords.ToString() +
                ", Normal: " + Normal.ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

I am clearly doing something wrong, but I don't know what it could be. I'm rotating the vertices first, then translating them. Am I missing something here?

Comment: You might want to pre-generate a bounding box based on your wall's transform and geometry and render it at runtime as say _**red** wireframe_.  Useful for debugging purposes.  Also, consider calculating and storing the wall's world transform ahead of time rather than calculate each time per collision detection

Comment: @MickyD The way that my geometry is designed, some pieces would be broken using purely bounding boxes, such as my corner pieces. You would not be able to fly within the L shape, because the bounding box would erroneously trigger it due to you being within a volume; I already considered this. Once I get this working, I will also be adding a second layer of hit detection (with a larger sphere) around the camera for soft collision. Only geometry within the soft collision will be tested by the next stage. Performance penalties will be negligible as a result.

Comment: @MickyD Plus, I really like the idea of being able to fit the camera within small spaces, such as the alcove with the cobweb and skull. My game will be completely free-flight camera; I want the hit detection to be very interactive. Not just "Yep, that's a box". In short, I want per-triangle collision detection.

Comment: No problem.  Consider using _hierarchical bounding volumes_.  In any event, you really need to visualise at runtime what your collision detection is doing at runtime, whatever form it takes.  Your transform order is correct and is following the _RST_ rule.

Comment: @MickyD I'd be more keen on just precalculating the triangles and storing them in a list within the geometry. The triangles are then rebuilt whenever the model is moved or rotated. I also only do this detection when the camera moves. I really appreciate your suggestions, though!

Comment: Not a problem good sir

Comment: @MickyD Just figured it out. About to post an answer. I was being an idiot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I was just being dumb. The way that you actually rotate a vertex is with `Vector3.TransformCoordinate();` and feed it the rotation matrix of the model. Here is the updated and working code (Which is pretty glorious to see working in person).

```
if (isCameraMoving)
            {
                foreach (StaticGeometry geometry in this.StaticGeometry)
                {
                    BoundingSphere cameraSphere = Camera.Bounds;
                    for (int i = 0; i < geometry.Mesh.Vertices.Length; i += 3)
                    {
                        // Get the Vertex Positions for the current Triangle
                        Vector3 position1 = geometry.Mesh.Vertices[i].Location;
                        Vector3 position2 = geometry.Mesh.Vertices[i + 1].Location;
                        Vector3 position3 = geometry.Mesh.Vertices[i + 2].Location;

                        // Create the rotation matrix using the geometry's current rotation setting.
                        Matrix rotationMatrix = VoidwalkerMath.CreateRotationMatrix(geometry.Rotation);

                        // Transform the Coordinate with the Rotation Matrix, then add the geometry's location
                        Vector3 finalVertexLocation1 = Vector3.TransformCoordinate(position1, rotationMatrix) + geometry.Location;
                        Vector3 finalVertexLocation2 = Vector3.TransformCoordinate(position2, rotationMatrix) + geometry.Location;
                        Vector3 finalVertexLocation3 = Vector3.TransformCoordinate(position3, rotationMatrix) + geometry.Location;

                        // Do hit detection for a triangle.
                        if (cameraSphere.Intersects(ref finalVertexLocation1, ref finalVertexLocation2, ref finalVertexLocation3))
                        {
                            this.Camera.Location = previousCameraPosition;
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p1PnwVhx0Sc

Comment: @MickyD Happy coding, my dude!